# How to indent even/odd numbered lines of a text file using vim

Tags: vim, vi

I wanted to indent only even numbered lines in a text file using vim.
In vim manual, indentation techniques are mentioned. But this will work either for a range of lines or particular line in which cursor positioned. I need a single command that should align the whole file. Is this possible in vim. Shall someone suggest on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To indent even lines:

```
:g/^/if line('.') % 2==0 | norm! >> | endif
```

to indent odd lines replace `2==0` with `2!=0`.

Comment: Wow. It's working.  Just curious to know how you identified this.

Comment: I found an answer in [vi stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/substitution-in-every-other-line) that uses `getcurpos()` to make a global substitution on even lines. I used a similar idea, but using `line()`  and `norm! >>`.